# Passing arguments to my function with do_action and add_action is not working

Tags: functions, actions, wp-enqueue-script

I have this code and the $var1 arrives empty to my function i dont know why, i've tested declaring the variable inside the function and it does work but when i try to declare it outside the function and pass it as a parameter with the do_action it doesn't work, any insights on this ? thanks

The add_shortcode works fine

```
$name="link";   
    add_shortcode($name, 'aa_link_shortcode' );

    function shorcode_resources($var1) {
        global $post;
       $shortcode_found = false;

       if ( has_shortcode($post->post_content, $var1) ) {
          $shortcode_found = true;
       } 

       if ( $shortcode_found ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'core', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/css/flipbox.css' , false ); 
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js',ABS_URL . '/shortcode/js/flipbox('.$var1.').js', false );
       }

}

do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', $name);    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shorcode_resources', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the `do_action` before the action is add, try moving it:

```
$name = "link";
add_shortcode($name, 'aa_link_shortcode');

function shorcode_resources($var1) {
    global $post;
    $shortcode_found = false;

    if (has_shortcode($post->post_content, $var1)) {
        $shortcode_found = true;
    }

    if ($shortcode_found) {
        wp_enqueue_style('core', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/css/flipbox.css', false);
        wp_enqueue_script('my-js', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/js/flipbox(' . $var1 . ').js', false);
    }
}

//first we add the action
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shorcode_resources', 10, 1);
//then we do the action
do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', $name);
```

also remember that `wp_enqueue_scripts` its an action that WP will trigger too

Comment: This seems correct!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure of the intent of this code, but more than likely the problem is that you are trying to change a built in hook. **wp_enqueue_scripts** is an actual WordPress hook that does not accept any arguments. Even though you declared you are passing one, when WP runs its **wp_enqueue_scripts** hook, it's going to ignore it. Maybe try using a global variable instead.

```
$shortcode_name="link";   
add_shortcode($shortcode_name, 'aa_link_shortcode' );

function shorcode_resources() {
   global $post, $shortcode_name;
   $shortcode_found = false;

   if ( has_shortcode($post->post_content, $shortcode_name) ) {
      $shortcode_found = true;
   } 

   if ( $shortcode_found ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'core', ABS_URL . '/shortcode/css/flipbox.css' , false ); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js',ABS_URL . '/shortcode/js/flipbox('.$shortcode_name.').js', false );
   }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shorcode_resources', 10 );
```

Comment: what are you talking about, the `$accepted_args` are for the `$function_to_add` for any action (hook), that includes `wp_enqueue_scripts`, read this please https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/